# Open generic type Autofac registration not able to resolve dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core, autofac

Have registered the autofac for open generic types for `ICommandHandler<TCommand,TResult>` but not able to resolve it on runtime . It plainly just says requested service has not been registered . I am not sure why is this happening .

```
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult>
    {
        Task<TResult> Handle(TCommand Command);
    }


public class LogniCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<LoginEvent,IActionResult>
    {

        public LogniCommandHandler()
        {
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Handle(LoginEvent command)
        {
              Console.WriteLine("This is a dependency call for ICommandHandler");
        }
    }
```

And **Startup.cs**. I am using Dotnet core with Autofac currently .

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            const string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost;database=MyAccount;trusted_connection=yes;";

            //services.AddAutofac();

            services.AddMvc()
                .AddControllersAsServices();



            BuildContainer(services);
            var serviceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
            return serviceProvider;
        }

        private void BuildContainer(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.Populate(services);

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
                .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>));

            builder.RegisterType<CommandDispatcher>()
                .As<ICommandDispatcher>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            container = builder.Build();
        }
```

And my **CommandDispatcher.cs** looks like this --

```
public class CommandDispatcher : ICommandDispatcher
    {
        ILifetimeScope scope;
        public CommandDispatcher(ILifetimeScope scope)
        {
            this.scope = scope;
        }

        public async Task<TResult> Handle<TCommand, TResult>(TCommand command)
        {
           //The exception occurs here while trying to get the generic type for the call 
            ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult> handler = scope.Resolve<ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult>>();
            return await handler.Handle(command);
        }
    }
```

The call for the dispatcher has been made like this -

```
 IActionResult result = await _dispatcher.Handle<IEvent, IActionResult>(new LoginEvent
                {
                    Email = model.Email,
                    Password = model.Password,
                    RememberLogin = model.RememberLogin,
                    RememberMe = model.RememberMe,
                    Username = model.Username
                });
```

**Exception --**

> ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'MyAccount.Identity.Eventing.ICommandHandler`2[[MyAccount.Identity.Eventing.IEvent, MyAccount.Identity, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]]' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

Comment: You should try with `await _dispatcher.Handle<LoginEvent, IActionResult>` because your `LogniCommandHandler` implements this interface `ICommandHandler<LoginEvent,IActionResult>`

Comment: @nemesv Okay let me try once .  I am sorry .

Comment: @Joy This looks like a covariance issue `IEvent` vs `LoginEvent`. based on the exception message and the example implementation.

Comment: @Nkosi So how to resolve this ? I want to Keep `IEvent` as default input for calling

Comment: @Joy you will need to refactor to `class LogniCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<IEvent,IActionResult>` But that may be too general.

Comment: @Nkosi yes that would be too specific . It won't be generic which I want to be actually

Comment: And why do you call it as `Handle<IEvent, IActionResult>`? Since you pass LoginEvent there, you can call as Handle<LoginEvent, IActionResult>

Comment: @Evk since I am passing an implementation of IEvent that is why

Comment: I understand that is valid to use IEvent here. But still, if you use Handle<LoginEvent, IActionResult>(new LoginEvent ...) - will that work?

Comment: @Evk yes it does work . actually

Comment: Well then you can call like this. The reason it fails is because implementation you request (with IEvent) is indeed not registered. Handler which handles only LoginEvents cannot handle all IEvents.